# Navigation bar buttons fall in one place

Tags: html, css

I've only started programming with html two days ago, I've searched all over the internet for a solution to my problem. Know this, that my html knowledge is very poor at this moment so please don't be harsh.

My problem is that the navigation bar I came up with is being lumped into one place.

```css
.button {
    position: fixed;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #E7EDE7;
    color: #0d96d6;
    line-height: 3em;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-family: courier new;
    -moz-transition: 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: 1s linear;
    -o-transition: 1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: 1s linear;
    transition: 1s linear;
}
.mainn {
    width: 64em;
    height: 25em;
    position: fixed;
}
.menuu {
    background-color: #E7EDE7;
    height: 3em;
    position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="menuu">
    <div class="mainn">
        <a class="button" href="home.html"> Home </a>
        <a class="button" href="contacts.html"> Contacts </a>
        <a class="button" href="pictures.html"> Pictures </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Mainn and menuu are classes not ids use . Instead of #

Comment: And really you only need the container element (first div) to be fixed position.

Comment: I changed it. Problem still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is luckily a pretty simple problem. You just need to remove `position: fixed` from the styling for your buttons, as this is what is causing them to overlap!

You can get a better understanding of how layout and positioning works in CSS by looking at [The Mozilla documentation for the position attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). Setting an item's position to `fixed` lays it out on the page relative to the parent element *without* any consideration for sibling elements.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `position:fixed` from your button class.

Also use the `.` for targeting classes.

`#menuu` should be `.menuu`

you have `position:fixed;` on all your buttons and have not set a `top`, `bottom`, `left`, or `right` so the will all default to `top:0;` and `left:0;` which will in turn stack them all

For reference, read [this](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/) article about CSS positioning

Comment: But I want my navigation bar to have a fixed position. By the way, I tried and it doesn't fix the problem :/

Comment: You just need `postion: fixed` on the wrapping element (i.e. the `class="menuu"`) not everything inside

Answer (score 0):

On your button class you may want to change to

```
display: inline
```

and add a

```
width
```